# Can i set the type for field as other array of dto. Of course with working validation in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator

I have two dto for entities Question and Answer. The entities Question and Answer have OneToMany relation. I going to make creation of questions with answers. So the field answer in the entity Question will take an array of answer items. That's why i need to set the type of answer as CreateAnswerDto[].

```
// create-answer.dto.ts

export class CreateAnswerDto {
    @ApiProperty({ example: "This is a variant of question's answer" })
    @IsEmpty()
    @IsString()
    @MaxLength(250)
    value: string;

    // ...

    @ApiProperty({ example: false })
    @IsBoolean()
    @Transform(({ obj, key }) => Boolean(obj[key]))
    isCorrect: boolean;
}
```

And finally question dto

```
// create-question.dto.ts

export class CreateQuestionDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    title: string;
    
    // ...

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsArray()
    answers: CreateAnswerDto[];
}
```

Is it possible to use other dto as type and will it validate these fields ?

Like:

```
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  answers: CreateAnswerDto[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it's possible.

You should add 2 decorators to achieve this:

- `@ValidateNested({ each: true })` - To set validation on each nested object in the array.
- `@Type()` - Specify the type of the object that the array contains.

So it will look like this:

```
import { ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer'; 

@IsNotEmpty()
@IsArray()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => CreateAnswerDto)
answers: CreateAnswerDto[];
```